# Change domain url in run time using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dns

My website url is https://socialappshq.com .I want to change this url according user requirement. I have a form to user to fill his domain name. Suppose that user enter xyz.com in field . After this if user hit on browser xyz.com then browser open my site  how can i do this. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot change the whole domain, instead you can use sub-domains

watch this tutorial.

> http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3